# SQLAlchemy Datetime with SQLite test cases

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a model like so:

```py
class MyModel(Base):


    submitter_id        = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id", name="fk_submitter"))
    submitter           = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[submitter_id])
    approver_id         = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id", name="fk_approver"))
    approver            = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[approver_id])
    approved_time       = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

When Im using the PSQL database in production, everything works as expected, but during testing im using an in-memory SQLite database. This seems to have some problems with the datetimes, as can be read on the docs: [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime)

"Date and time types return objects from the Python datetime module. Most DBAPIs have built in support for the datetime module, with the noted exception of SQLite. In the case of SQLite, date and time types are stored as strings which are then converted back to datetime objects when rows are returned."

This to me sounds like the ORM layer should handle  the situation where I need to store datetimes. But when Im running my tests that invoke a fixture creating instances of `MyModel` I get the following error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
E           [SQL: INSERT INTO x (created, updated, created_by_id, is_deleted, , , ,, ,, submitter_id, approver_id, approved_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
E           [parameters: [{'<redacted>',  'approved_time': '2021-01-13T09:50:23.1682 ... (308 characters truncated) ... <redacted>}]]
```

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```py
#Set up seeding of database for testing purposes
mymodel1 = MyModel()
mymodel1.a = "b"
mymodel1.b = "c"
#etc
mymodel1.created = datetime.datetime.now()
mymodel1.approved_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

How should I go about making the ORM work with me in this case?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  I can create and commit such an object without error.  Note that in your example, `MyModel` mostly consists of references to some other table, and has no `approved_time` attribute.

Comment: What did you do to fix it? @enrm

Comment: @SüleymanSümertaş I ended up setting up a PSQL database for testing aswell..